# Async / await not working " string does not contain a defination fot GetAwaiter " and no extension

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, visual-studio-2015, xamarin.android

I am making Android App in Visual Studio Xamarin, in App's Login screen when the connection is made with DataBase through Web Services for verification of password I want to show a progressDialog until connection is made.

Here's my code on the onclient side:

```
private string login()
{
    string x = null;
    var progress = ProgressDialog.Show(this, "waiting", "Loading");
    progress.SetProgressStyle(ProgressDialogStyle.Spinner);
    new Thread(new ThreadStart(delegate
    {
        RunOnUiThread(async () =>
        {
            x = await services.Verification("abc", "xyz");
            progress.Dismiss();
        });
     })).Start();

    return x;
}
```

On the server side:

```
public string Verification(string userName, string password)
{
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"");
    conn.Open();
    string query = "select category from ACCOUNTS where loginId = '" + userName + "' and pasword= '" + password + "'";
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query);
    cmd.Connection = conn;
    string catagory = null;
    SqlDataReader account = cmd.ExecuteReader();

    if (account.HasRows)
    {
        if (account.Read())
        {
            catagory = account[0].ToString();
        }
    }
    conn.Close();

    return catagory;
}
```

Here's the error in login() function on line `x = await services.Verification("abc", "xyz");` and it says:

```
 'String' does not contain a definition for 'GetAwaiter' and no extension method 'GetAwaiter' accepting a first argument of type 'String' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

Comment: As the error is trying to tell you, you can't await `string`.  You need to use some actual async APIs.

Comment: like what? i am new to this.....plz help!

Comment: `and pasword= '" + password + "'"` - I just... I just... am speechless. For the love of the Internet, **please** get some security training before putting this into production. Tony Hunt has a [great video](https://www.pluralsight.com/courses/owasp-top10-aspdotnet-application-security-risks) available.

Answer (score 1):

To use this:

```
x = await services.Verification("abc", "xyz");
```

You have to use an API like:

```
public async Task<string> Verification(string userName, string password)
```

However, what are you using to communicate with the DB?  It looks like you are directly calling the Verification method directly, instead of invoking the service through REST.  Calling the method directly won't work when you deploy the app...  You need to invoke a proxy to a web service using HttpClient with async/await, RestSharp, or others defined in this tutorial: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/application_fundamentals/web_services/.

Taken from [here](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/advanced/async_support_overview/):

```
var httpClient = new HttpClient();
Task<string> contentsTask = httpClient.GetStringAsync("http://xamarin.com"); 

string contents = await contentsTask;
```

Comment: I am using WEB SERVICES (ASMX) n Server is on Azure, as you said after using, the ERROR is

 ' 'TaskOfString' does not contain a definition for 'GetAwaiter' and no extension method 'GetAwaiter' accepting a first argument of type 'TaskOfString' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) ' plzzz help!!

Comment: The example you indicated above is not awaitable because it doesn't implement async Task<string> in the first place.  However, did you setup a proxy or something?  Because when I used Xamarin to connect, I needed to use the code sample as I  mentioned above, but use `httpClient.GetStringAsync("HTTP PATH TO WEB SERVICE ON SERVER");`

Comment: i am adding web references(ASMX) to my code...
 [here you can see](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/application_fundamentals/web_services/#asmx) 

can you plzz help me how to do that...make a "awaitable" that implement "async"

Comment: OK cool, my bad.  Did you try making the web service with Task<string> as I indicated above?  Try that and see if the proxy assumes that.

Comment: yes i tried that.....same error but this time "TaskOfString"

'TaskOfString does not contain a definition for 'GetAwaiter' and no extension method 'GetAwaiter' accepting a first argument of type 'TaskOfString' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)'

Comment: Look at the proxy code being generated.  I'm willing to guess that the proxy generation for the web service doesn't support async/await.  If the case, in order for async/await to work, you have to use HttpClient or RestSharp or other tool.